# Application Page now Empty

Tags: facebook-page

ON this page I had an RSS Feed from my Homepage (www.stafflink.fi), but now this application page is Empty.
http://www.facebook.com/stafflink
 -> http://apps.facebook.com/stafflink/
Something changed what I indeed missed.

Comment: Is your server providing the resources via HTTPS?

Comment: The server provides the Homepage, as I added it as Page Tab, only without https.
Page Tab URL: http://www.stafflink.fi
Secure Page Tab URL: http://www.stafflink.fi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add https in application settings (without it it shows blank page).

Comment: As of Oct 2011, you need to setup an https version of your canvas URL too.